# Function Names as HTML Attribute

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I know that functions can be stored on html attributes for specific events (e.g. onmouseover), but can any attribute refer to a function or just the special attributes?

I would like to automatically wire the ajax success and failure call backs based on the form attributes [e.g. onsuccess="alert('whoohoo');" and onfail="alert('You suck');"].  Is something like that possible, or would I have to store the function on a known event and trigger the event on fail or success?

---

I wanted to share the result code with SO for the benifit of the community.  Unfortunally I could not use data-* as the attribute name due to '-' not being valid char for a property name and forms are created using MVC and anonymous types.

```
// provide the ability to manually setup a form for ajax processing.
// target are the forms to be wired
// success is the callback function
function AjaxifyForms(target, success, fail) {
    $(target).each(function() {       // Wierdness if each isn't used with validation
        $(this).validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({                                                           //create an AJAX request
                    type: "POST",                                                  //use POST (we could also load this from the form if wanted to)
                    url: $(form).attr("action"),                       //get the URL from the form
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (success != undefined && success != null) success(data);
                        else if ($(form).attr("ajaxSuccssCallback") != undefined && $(form).attr("ajaxSuccssCallback") != null)
                            window[$(form).attr("ajaxSuccssCallback")](data);
                        else alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        if (faile != undefined && fail != null) fail(data);
                        else if ($(form).attr("ajaxFailCallback") != undefined && $(form).attr("ajaxFailCallback") != null)
                            window[$(form).attr("ajaxFailCallback")](data);
                        else alert("Epic Fail");
                    }
                });
                return false;                            //don't forget to cancel the event so we don't submit the page!
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You could do some browser tests to see what works and what doesn't. That's what I'm about to do.

Comment: I would like to do the same thing for the purpose of serialization, but it looks like you didn't find a way to do it that would work for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach would be to use the `data-*` attributes from HTML5, and to only store function names, not actual executable JavaScript code. For example,

```
<form id="MyForm" data-success-callback="woohoo" data-failure-callback="suck" />
```

Then get references to those functions via

```
var successFunc = window[$("#MyForm").attr("data-success-callback")];
var failureFunc = window[$("#MyForm").attr("data-failure-callback")];
```

This only works if they're global functions; otherwise you would need to do something a bit trickier (like splitting on `.`s and then using index notation) to get the function reference.

Comment: ok, but suppose you want to serialize the actual executable javascript code - suppose it is dynamically generated or something, such that storing a function name won't work because that function won't exist later and thus the code must actually be in an HTML attribute?

Answer (score 1):

the HTML 5 spec has a list of all the [valid event handler attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements-document-objects-and-window-objects)

I am of the opinion that the best way to handle custom events (with jQuery) is to bind them in a script, and trigger them manually.

Ex.

```
$('#myForm').bind('prefix-success', mySuccessFunction)
  .bind('prefix-fail', myFailFunction);
```

then when it fails or succeeds, you trigger the proper function

```
if (success) $('#myForm').trigger('prefix-success');
else if (fail) $('#myForm').trigger('prefix-fail');
```

Of course, this is an oversimplificiation of the issue at hand. You're going to want to create a generic way of calling/binding the events.

I suggest using an event prefix so that you can be certain that your events aren't overwritten in later HTML specs.

Edit to add:
I forgot to mention *why* keeping the functions in the script is best:

HTML is for semantic markup (model). CSS is for styles (view). JavaScript is for interactions (controller). Keep the control specifics in the controller, so that you don't clutter up your model.

Comment: that is a very narrow view of MVC